# It is okay to install ASP.NET MVC 4 along ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

It is okay to install ASP.NET MVC 4 along ASP.NET MVC 3 ? or will it break anything from MVC 3 already in place ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this page:  http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes

> **Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4**
>
> ASP.NET MVC 4 can be installed side by side with ASP.NET MVC 3 on the
>   same computer, which gives you flexibility in choosing when to upgrade
>   an ASP.NET MVC 3 application to ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

I did a comparison to my cs.proj file.

Change the ProjectGuid from C474BC22-B54A-4EF6-B4D5-C8277E1B0916, to F043A0B8-F6E1-47CE-9EE1-EBC6ACA61B15. Click reload project in Sln file.

I tried everything else, changing ProjectTypeGuids in the csproj file, repaired MVC4 From Programs, reinstalling MVC 3 after removing the Nuget Package Manager because of a conflict between the WebPlatForm installer. Then installing  SP1 for VS2010. To no avail.